# iOS 9 new feature of "back navigation" to previous App in statusbar

Tags: navigation, statusbar, ios9

In my Application, I am using login through FB. In iOS 9 Beta, as new feature I get "< back to Fb" button in status bar.

How can I handle it? Can we stop redirecting back? or anything else?

Thanks in advance.